# How to get product carousel in the Google search results that the Google documentation says is only for news articles?

Tags: google-search, search-results, rich-snippets, rich-cards

In this picture, in the carousel cards all link to the same website.

[image]

How to get this carousel?

I searched and found that it is available only for `NewsArticle` schema,  but the pages are of `Product` schema. (Search for "honda bikes" on google.co.in)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you access the page (https://auto.ndtv.com/honda-bikes/grazia) and run it through the structured data testing tool (https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) you will see that the page includes four types of structured data. The relevant one is Product, and it has 12 warnings: the markup uses datePublished, reviewBody, author, and reviewRating. Google does not recognize any of these properties for object type Product.

It's possible that, by using some of the structured data you might find in an Article or a Recipe (which are supported for carousels, per https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings), they got this to display in a carousel. (This may not have been done on purpose, could just be a lucky "side effect" of incorrect code.)

This sometimes happens. However, there is no guarantee that Google will continue to display these search results in a carousel after future crawls.

Of note, I didn't see any list markup on the previous / aggregator page (https://auto.ndtv.com/honda-bikes/) but there could be another aggregator page at a different URL; also, they could be loading it on mobile only. Finally, Google is constantly tweaking its own rules, so unexpected things are sometimes caught in the wild before they make it into the official documentation.